# How do I avoid None as result of a query?

Tags: python, string, sqlite, null

So I am trying to put the result of a query in a string. Let's say row by row (I don't need all the fields by the way), but that's not the point. I am using python against a sqlite db.

the problem is that when some of the fields are null, python will write None instead of "" or some blank neutral thing.

example:

```
   t = "%s %s %s %s" % (field[1],field[2],field[3],field[4])
```

If field[3] is null for instance, t will be something like

```
"string1 string2 None string4"
```

instead of

```
"string1 string2 string4"
```

yes I would need to remove also the double space in case. I cannot just replace "None" with "" because some string might contain itself "None" since it is a common word. Of course I don't have only 4 field, they are a lot, and I am not trying to import every field of the row, only specific ones. I need a fast and easy way to fix this behavior. I cannot manually check if each field is None, that's insane. I cannot use

```
str.strip(field[i])
```

because when the field is None I get an error.

what could be a good approach?

Comment: Why can't you check every field for "None"?  Is it a speed issue, or a coding issue?  If it's a coding issue, you should be able to do it in a loop.

Comment: because it is a lot of fields. I don't understand why %s converts None which is a Nonetype in "None" string. I just want to avoid this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the *str.replace* option if "None " is unique to NULL fields:

```
>>> "string1 string2 None string4".replace('None ', '')
'string1 string2 string4'
```

Or you can pre-filter the strings:

```
>>> fields = ['string0', 'string1', 'string2', None, 'string4']
>>> fields_out = filter(lambda f: f is not None, fields[1:])
>>> template = ' '.join('%s' for field in fields_out)
>>> template % tuple(fields_out)
'string1 string2 string4'
```

Comment: this won't work. what if string2 = "None of my friends"? I am going to replace that "None " as well, even if I am not supposed to.

Comment: That's why I gave you the second option to pre-filter the fields prior to substituion.

Comment: Or `fields_out = [field for field in fields if field is not None]`. Or if you don't mind removing anything that evaluates to `bool(False)`, `[field for field in fields if field]`.

Comment: -1 `filter(None, ...)` removes zeroes -- the OP has given no indication that all columns contain strings.

Comment: Then use an appropriate lambda for the filter.  Don't be daft.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger: Welcome to SO. If the OP could work that out himself, he wouldn't have needed to ask the question in the first place. He doesn't understand why `"%s" % None` produces `'None'`. He probably doesn't grok "an appropriate lambda for the filter".

Answer (score 0):

Form the sql with only the fields which are not `None`:

```
names=('col1','col2','col3')
fields=...
data=dict((n,f) for n,f in zip(names,fields) if f is not None)
condition=' AND '.join('{n} = ?'.format(n=n) for n in data)
sql='''SELECT {n} FROM table
       WHERE {c}
       '''.format(n=','.join(data.keys()),c=condition)
args=data.values()
cursor.execut(sql,args)
```

Comment: I am not actually inserting data. I perform a select. Null values are converted in None by python, and if I use %s to create a string I get the word "None" which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over your select statement, you could always use the [ifnull](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull) function to format any potential null values:

```
select
   ifnull(fieldx, '') as fieldx
from table
```

This will make sure that the returned value is an empty string rather than a null value. Of course this may not be practical if you have a lot of potential null fields.

If that doesn't work, I'd say Raymond Hettinger's suggestion is the most direct method.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you say that you want to do:

```
t = " ".join("%s" % x for x in your_tuple if x is not None)
```

Given that you don't want extra spaces, it would be a good idea to remove zero-length strings also:

```
t = " ".join("%s" % x for x in your_tuple if x is not None and x != "")
```

Example:

```
>>> your_tuple = ('foo', None, '', 0, 1, 'bar')
>>> " ".join("%s" % x for x in your_tuple if x is not None)
'foo  0 1 bar'
>>> " ".join("%s" % x for x in your_tuple if x is not None and x != "")
'foo 0 1 bar'
```

**Warning**: `filter(None, your_data)` is NOT a good idea:

```
>>> filter(None, your_tuple)
('foo', 1, 'bar') # Whoops!
```

Comment: Trivial variant of another answer.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger: trivial to you, not to the OP.

Comment: unfortunately this helps if I want to import the whole tuple into a string. I just need specific fields. what I am doing now, is to list them all, and check for everyone if they are None. The brute way